# Query to return highest value and name from two tables over two columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum, max

I'm trying to pull a one row result, (two or more if its a tie) from the following query.  The problem is, its returning three rows, and not just a single row containing the unit_name with the highest total HP, which is a combination of HP and Shields.

The query in english
   Which unit has the most total defense?

The query...

```
select unit_name, max(hp + shield) as totalHealth
from
(
select unit_name, hp, shield from units
where hp = (select max(hp) from units)
union 
select unit_name, hp, shield from units
where shield =(select max(shield) from units)
) d
group by unit_name
```

the result...

```
unit_name       totalhealth
Archon          360
Battlecruiser   550
Mothership      700
```

I would hope the query would just return Mothership and 700,
something like this....

```
unit_name      totalHealth
Mothership     700
```

I'm using postgres

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `hp` and `shield` together to get the total health.  You can then use a ranking function to get the rows with the highest value.  So, assuming that `hp` and `shield` are not `NULL`:

```
select u.*
from (select u.unit_name, sum(hp + shield) as totalhealth,
             rank() over (order by sum(hp + shield) desc) as seqnum
      from units u
      group by unit_name
     ) u
where seqnum = 1;
```